# Importing bz2 compressed binary file as numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, bzip2

I have a bz2 compressed binary (big endian) file containing an array of data. Uncompressing it with external tools and then reading the file in to Numpy works:

```
import numpy as np
dim = 3
rows = 1000
cols = 2000
mydata = np.fromfile('myfile.bin').reshape(dim,rows,cols)
```

However, since there are plenty of other files like this I cannot extract each one individually beforehand. Thus, I found the bz2 module in Python which might be able to directly decompress it in Python. However I get an error message:

```
dfile = bz2.BZ2File('myfile.bz2').read()
mydata = np.fromfile(dfile).reshape(dim,rows,cols)

>>IOError: first argument must be an open file
```

Obviously, the BZ2File function does not return a file object. Do you know what is the correct way read the compressed file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BZ2File` *does* return a file-like object (although not an actual file). The problem is that you're calling `read()` on it:

```
dfile = bz2.BZ2File('myfile.bz2').read()
```

This reads the entire file into memory as one big string, which you then pass to `fromfile`.

Depending on your versions of `numpy` and `python` and your platform, reading from a file-like object that isn't an actual file may not work. In that case, you can use the buffer you read in with `frombuffer`.

So, either this:

```
dfile = bz2.BZ2File('myfile.bz2')
mydata = np.fromfile(dfile).reshape(dim,rows,cols)
```

… or this:

```
dbuf = bz2.BZ2File('myfile.bz2').read()
mydata = np.frombuffer(dbuf).reshape(dim,rows,cols)
```

(Needless to say, there are a slew of other alternatives that might be better than reading the whole buffer into memory. But if your file isn't too huge, this will work.)

Comment: `frombuffer()` doesn't seem to work in python2.7. It fails with `AttributeError: 'ExFileObject' object has no attribute '__buffer__'`. Any idea why?

Comment: Never mind, I was using `zipfl = bz2.BZ2File('myfile.bz2').open('file_memver_in_archive')` because I wanted to get `dbuf.name` and other attributes of the member. However, if  one aclutally needs `zipfl` to be an `ExFileObjcet`, like I do, one can simply do `mydata = np.frombuffer(zipfl.read())` and have the best of both worlds.

Comment: BTW, using np.fromfile directly to the bz2 file, does not work for me, but np.frombuffer works fine.